# How does incandescent lamp mounting influence color temperature?

Tags: optics, thermal-radiation

I have a high power incandescent halogen lamp, which I want to mount behind a pane of glass some distance away, such as to minimize that funky burning dust smell, that I really dislike.

Now say this is a borosilicate glass, and the reflector is a parabolic such that many of the rays come in approximately normal to the glass, and its an uncoated glass. Then about 10% of the light would be sent back; a lot of it straight back to the filament. Lets assume the filament is a black body. Also this probably impacts convective cooling, but lets ignore this for a second.

That would imply about a 10% max additional energy to re-radiate; or like running my lamp at 10% over rated power; something rather significant that would wreck its lifetime, if not burn it out outright?

Is that 10% estimate way over? Im ignoring the fact that might light also needs to go back through the quartz envelope, but that seems like a higher order effect. I suppose the biggest factor in practice is that my filament is small, and its hard to get it in the exact focal point of where the internally reflected light reconvenes within my reflector, even if i tried. And in fact if I take some care to tweak my geometry such that my lamp stays clear of the focal spot, im not going to get anywhere near that 10%, and will probably stay well under a single percent? Most of that light reflected at the front pane will just make it out in subsequent bounces?

Youd think this would be a common concern that lamp manufacturers would have rules of thumb to offer on; but so far ive found nothing.

Comment: Without a full spex of the desired spectral flatness and the type of glass used it's impossible to guess the spectrum of the resulting light. CTemp is not a single value that you are probably caring about; the whole spectrum is. All grades of fused BSi optics-grade glasses have the transmissibility of about 90% per 10 mm in the ballpark, and the relation is more logarithmic than linear. A .5mm glass will absorb or reflect no more than .15% of light. What part of spectrum do you need the most blackbody-ish? And the smell is likely not dust but your fingerprints. Are you using nitrile gloves?

Comment: Its not my fingerprints. Not sure where you get the idea that the thickness of the glass thats the only thing? First of all im probably looking at a few mm; but there is also the 4% or so straight up reflection at the refractive index boundary, even for normal rays, no?

In the end its not so much the resulting spectral properties that I care about, as it is the literal temperature of the filament. High temp tungsten halogen lamps are already pushing the limit of what doesnt straight up melt the filament, and lifetime is a strong function of temp.

Comment: Halogens bulbs produce primarily heat. The lifetime of the bulb is determined by thermal considerations. The reflectivity of the glass plays only a minor role as compared to how it impacts airflow and heat transfer.

Comment: Yeah to what extent convective heat transfer is actually important when it comes to secondary glass layers isnt something I have a great intuitive sense of, nor have seen any quantitative arguments about. My guess is its less than the reflection but I could be wrong. I think all of this would be more effort than its worth to model from first principles; buying a pane of glass and risking overheating some bulbs is going to be cheaper. But I was hoping there would be some decent reference material on this topic.